# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have to parse this web page http://india.gov.in/topics/health-family-welfare/health

I am supposed to get the headings my code is here ,it is not at all printing the headings what's wrong

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2
from mechanize import Browser
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


import sys
import csv

mech = Browser()
url = "http://www.india.gov.in/topics/health-family-welfare/health"
page = mech.open(url)

html = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
div=soup.find("div",{"class":"view-content"})
lists = div.find('ol')
for ol in lists:
lis=ol.findAll('li')
print lis

print
```

Her is the error i got

```
 File "srap_req.py", line 17, in <module>
lists = div.findAll('ol')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

Comment: `lists` is **not** a list, so why loop over it?

Comment: Please always include the full traceback of an exception.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using BeautifulSoup 3 instead of BeautifulSoup 4? BeautifulSoup 3 hasn't seen a new release in 2 years now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i have installed buetifulSoup 4,is there any difference in calling buetifulSoup4 in python file,if so can you please explain.It would be grateful

Comment: Your traceback doesn't match your code; in that case there was no `<div class="view-content">` to find and `div` is now `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div` is `None`, because on the preceding line the `.find()` call did not find a matching `<div class="view-content">`. You loaded a page without such a div on it. If you are parsing multiple pages, you have to take into account that `.find()` calls won't actually find the object you are looking for and return `None` instead.

I strongly recommend you switch to BeautifulSoup 4 here instead. BeautifulSoup 3 hasn't seen any new releases of bug fixes for over 2 years now, and BeautifulSoup 4 lets you use [CSS queries](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to get what you want, which is a lot easier:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

mech = Browser()
url = "http://www.india.gov.in/topics/health-family-welfare/health"
page = mech.open(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
for item in soup.select('div.view-content ol li'):
    print item
```

If you are using `mechanize`, you may also want to look at [RoboBrowser](http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/), a more modern re-implementation, using `requests` and BeautifulSoup:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

browser = RoboBrowser()
url = "http://www.india.gov.in/topics/health-family-welfare/health"
browser.open(url)

for item in browser.select('div.view-content ol li'):
    print item
```