# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'

Tags: python

I am new to python. Please help me with this error.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'
```

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import requests

url = 'https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Event-Organisers/nct-10194150'

req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"}) 

page = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

for h in soup.findAll('h2'):
    a = h.find('a')

    if 'href' in a.attrs:
        l = a.get('href')

    print l
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828115/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-findall)

Comment: I understand closing the question as a duplicate, but as off topic? It's pretty clear what the desired behaviour is, even if it's not worded in the best way. Correct me if I'm wrong of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use try-except to avoid `NoneType` exception:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import requests

url = 'https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Event-Organisers/nct-10194150'

req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"}) 

page = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

for h in soup.findAll('h2'):
    a = h.find('a')
    try:
        if 'href' in a.attrs:
            l = a.get('href')
    except:
        pass

    print l
```

**OR:**
check if `a` is None:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import requests

url = 'https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Event-Organisers/nct-10194150'

req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"}) 

page = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

for h in soup.findAll('h2'):
    a = h.find('a')

    if a is not None and 'href' in a.attrs:
        l = a.get('href')

    print l
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks.

Comment: How do I make it work for multiple pages? This works just for a single page. Please help me. @godot

Comment: I need real examples to understand what you mean

Answer (score 3):

You should nil check the `a` element. It seems like there are no `a` tags in `h2`, hence `a` is `NoneType`

```
if a and 'href' in a.attrs:
    l = a.get('href')
```

Comment: Yep,  correct add a conditional check whether there is `a` in h2 or not  Something  like `a = h.find('a')     if a:        if 'href' in a.attrs:            l = get('href')         print (l) `

Comment: yep, thanks, added a suggested check.

Answer (score 0):

some of the elements you inspect are None, you should make sure the "a" element you found does actually have the attrs attribute, you can use `hasattr` built-in function:

```
hasattr(a, "attrs")
```

will return true if a has attrs and false if it does not.
read about [this function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr%20%7C%20link)